# transforming date from xml to csv using dataweave

Tags: date, mule, dataweave

I want to transform a date which is attribute coming from xml file into csv format using dataweave. now, transformation rule is 'If date is Sunday, make the date minus 6 days'. otherwise keep as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is something like this -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <createDate>2016-05-08</createDate>
</root>
```

Then you can use below dataweave code to get date as required. When the day is Sunday, subtract 6 days from date -

```
%dw 1.0
 %output application/csv
 ---
 {
     row: {
         date: (payload.root.createDate as :date) unless 
             (((payload.root.createDate as :date) as :string {format: "E"}) == 'Sun') 
                 otherwise ((payload.root.createDate as :date) - |P6D|)

                 }
 }
```

It will output as below -

```
date
2016-05-02
```